# When formflatten is set to false using PdfStamper still flattens few form fields

Tags: pdf, itext, xfa

I don't want my PDF file to be flattened by `PdfStamper`. So I am doing `stamper.setFormFlattening(false)`. But still there are few fields which are flattened. Most of them are dropdowns and checkboxes. Can I know what is making it to flatten?

Comment: For starters, you are using a very old and unsupported version. Please try again with iText 7.1.0.

Comment: With `setFormFlattening(false)` no form flattening takes place. What may happen, though, is that the PDF in question was Reader-enabled and you broke the usage rights signature with your stamping. The result can appear like form flattening, cf. [this recent question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/47581765/1729265). In that case be sure to use append mode or remove the usage rights signature altogether. If you need more help, give more information, in particular your pivotal code and a sample PDF to reproduce the issue with.

Answer (score 0):

You can check whether it is a 'reader-enabled'/extended rights PDF by opening that document in *dobe reader afterwards. Current versions then show an error message indicating a problem with the usage rights. Here's the code of what mkl describes:

```
PdfDictionary perms = stamper.getReader().getCatalog().getAsDict(PdfName.PERMS);

if (perms != null){
    perms.remove(PdfName.UR);
    perms.remove(PdfName.UR3);

    if (perms.size() == 0) stamper.getReader().getCatalog().remove(PdfName.PERMS);
}
```